# Expanding the zonal polynomial $Z_\lambda(x/(1-x))$

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions

Schur polynomials $s_\lambda(x)$ have a determinantal expression. Using that, I know how to write the polynomial $s_\lambda(\frac{x}{1-x})=s_\lambda(\frac{x_1}{1-x_1},\frac{x_2}{1-x_2},...)$ as an infinite linear combination of other Schur polynomials.

Sadly, zonal polynomials do not have a determinantal expression. Still, I would like to write the zonal polynomial $Z_\lambda(\frac{x}{1-x})$ as an infinite linear combination of other zonal polynomials.

Does someone know how to do this?

Let me focus on a particular case. When $\lambda=(A,1^a)$ is a hook, the Schur function expansion is very simple. It involves only hooks and binomial coefficients:
$$ s_{(A,1^a)}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{B\ge A,b\ge a} (-1)^{a+b}{b\choose a} {B-1\choose A-1}s_{(B,1^b)}(x).$$

Maybe $ Z_{(A,1^a)}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)$ has a similar expansion?

Let me report the result of some experimenting. If we write $Z_\lambda\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_\mu C_{\lambda\mu}Z_\mu(x)$, then I am confident that
$$ C_{(n),(m)}={m-1\choose n-1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2m-1)!!}$$
and
$$ C_{(1^n),(1^m)}=(-1)^{m+n}{m-1\choose n-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{(m+1)!}.$$
(I don't know how to prove these, they are conjectures).
However, $C_{(3),(4,1)}=-\frac{23}{120}$ and 23 is prime, so a very simple general formula is not so likely.

Comment: Wait, what is meant by $x/(1-x)$? Do you mean the plethystic substitution which evaluates the Schur in $y,y^2,y^3,\dotsc$ for all variables?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I mean $Z_\lambda(\frac{x_1}{1-x_1}, \frac{x_2}{1-x_2},\cdots,\frac{x_n}{1-x_n})$

Comment: So, there are power-sum expansions of the Jack polynomials known, and on these, your substitution is easy. However, expanding this back into Jack (or Zonal,  for the case alpha=2) seems hard

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Yes, that possibility has occurred to me. It is doable, but quite messy. For Schur functions there is a more direct approach, using a scalar product. I was hoping something like that could also work for zonals.

Comment: The one who I would ask is Valentin Feray. By the way, do you have a reference for the statement regarding the Schur functions?

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Thanks. For Schur functions I have done it in the appendix to this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.07419

Comment: Ah interesting. The coefficients in your formula, they have been studied before, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870885901215 (Binomial determinants, paths, and hook length formulae, by I. Gessel)

Comment: @PerAlexandersson : The Schur function case is handled generally in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.01581.pdf. Look at corollary 3.5. These are special cases of canonical stable Grothendieck polynomials.